# Text highlight with audio sync in Jquery

Tags: jquery, flash, audio, synchronization

I need to sync text and audio on many web pages.

While the audio is played the text should be highlighted phrase by phrase (not word by word or by character so sync is necessary only for the start of the phrase).

I'd like not to use a flash only solution and I'd prefer to use something more HTML friendly.

I thought to use a combination of two plugins:

- [JPlayer](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/) for the audio
- [Jquery highligheter](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) for highlighting the text

I could then write a jquery script to cycle on the various phrases.
The first problem is that JPlayer has only percentage played events and not precise timeline events so I would need to split the full mp3 audio of the spoken text in smaller audio files for each phrase (long editing work and preload management needed).

Is there a better solution for this? Should I go back to the easier full swf solution?

Comment: It's not only percentage-based - look here: http://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer/blob/master/jquery.jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js#L600 .. there is a `playedTime` var and a `totalTime` var (as the 4th and 5th arguments to your callback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is script the timeline in javascript. When the audio starts to play, you set timeouts for each action on the timeline. This will require your audio to play without any delays of course.

It would look something like this:

```
   <div>one</div>
   <div>two</div>
   <div>three</div>

<script>
// this is the timeline
var actions = [  { time : 1, action : function() { $('div:eq(0)').css('color','red') } },
                 { time : 1.5, action : function() { $('div:eq(1)').css('color','green') } },
                 { time : 2, action : function() { $('div:eq(2)').css('color','blue') } } ];

$(document).ready( function() {
        // execute the timeline
        for( var i in actions ) {
            setTimeout( actions[i].action, actions[i].time * 1000 );
        }
});

</script>
```

Comment: ALTAF HUSSAIN's comment: "@Marnix van Valen - Really cool snippet marnix, just what i require,
I wonder what if the video is loaded from a server (html5 video tag), then the text will start to show up before the video could load up.
Anyway of working around this, like having a preloader or anything."

Comment: For HTML5 video you have a [wealth of events and properties](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) you can use to sync actions to. For example, you could check the `currentTime` property at regular intervals and use that to trigger actions in the timeline. That would also allow you to compensate for any delays in loading the video.