# Can I sync HTML text or divs with SWF (Flash character animation)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, synchronization

I have flash animation (swf) in my HTML Page.

Now, I like to have my flash animated character (700kb) to speak dialogues, the related text should pop and go in the html side of the page.

I've already used this amazing cool script from [Text highlight with audio sync in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369559/text-highlight-with-audio-sync-in-jquery) by Marnix van Valen  & HTML5 works cool as he says. BUT, what about flash???.

Is there any way to do this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you need to run some code from flash file, there is a good tool for it - `ExternalInterface`

for example as3 code:

```
class Character {
  public function say(msg:String):void
  {
    trace(msg);
    ExternalInterface.call('say', msg);
  }
}
```

js code on the html page where your swf embedded:

```
<script>
function say(msg) {
  alert('character says: ' + msg);
}
</script>
```

So when you run character.say('hi') you'll get new message in flash console (from `trace`) and popup with your message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will add to this excellent answer that with `ExternalInterface` you can sync Flash and Javascript in the two ways : `ExternalInterface.call` calls JS from Flash, and `ExternalInterface.addCallback` add a flash function callable from JS. Don't forget to test compatibility with `ExternelInterface.available`